# How to I change the value of a property of an object on a function click in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular

employees = [{Id: 1001, Salary : 2000}, {Id: 1002, Salary: 1000}];

Expected Results:- I am displaying the above array on the browser. On a function click, I want the Salary to get multiplied by 12. ie the annual salary should be displayed on the web page. However on the function click I am multiplying the salary by using the map() of array and then pushing the newly calculated annual salary into the Salary property

Actual Results:- The newly calculated salary property is not getting pushed into the property of the students array.

code snippet:-

```
map() {
    this.annualSalary = this.students.map(a => a.Salary *  12 );
    this.annualSalary.forEach((as, index) => {
      let asalary = as;   
      this.students.push({

        Salary : asalary,
      });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solutions

```
    for (let index = 0; index < this.students.length; index++) {
      const element = this.students[index];
      this.students[index].Salary = element.Salary * 12
    }
```

Comment: I want to use map() and foreach() of the array.

Comment: But there is no need to use two loops for this operation, that will affect performance also

Comment: OHK , but what if i want to use foreach instead of for loop? and I am not using 2 loops .. Map is an array function

Comment: Here is solution using forEach `this.students.forEach(element => {
    element.Salary = element.Salary * 12;
});`

Comment: There is no need to use map() in this case then?

Comment: Yes, you does not need map function for performer this task.